# Fill datagrid with query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado

I am new to coding. Learn as I go, I want to fill a datagrid only with rows where my checkout is null

I want the specific data to show up on my datagrid that contain no checkout value. I have no clue what I am doing wrong. I am new in vb.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    datafile = "D:\Projects\ezchain\ezchain\data\ex.accdb"
    connec = provider & datafile
    mycon.ConnectionString = connec
    mycon.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * from Keys WHERE checkout = '' "
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, mycon)
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        mycon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
        mycon.Close()
        Me.KeysTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ExDataSet.keys)
    End Try
    Me.KeysTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ExDataSet.keys)
End Sub
```

Atm nothing pops, not even exception ... o.O

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE queries.  Not for SELECT.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out!